# How to parse a list of strings of URLs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I have an array that includes a list of strings of URLs like this:

```
urls=["https://www.ilfoglio.it/economia/2015/11/17/news/se-litalia-fosse-un-paese-indipendente-non-sarebbe-litalia-89688/", "https://design.fanpage.com/nakagin-capsule-tower-affitta-una-capsula-con-airbnb/", "https://www.fondazioneveronesi.it/magazine/articoli/oncologia/il-caffe-puo-proteggere-dai-tumori-del-fegato"]
```

and I would like to parse them in order to get

```
www.ilfoglio.it
design.fanpage.com
www.fondazioneveronesi.it
```

and their paths.

I have always used the following code when I was working with urls:

```
netloc=[] path=[]
count=0
for url in urls: 
    parsed=urlparse(url) 
    netloc.append(parsed.netloc) 
    path.append(parsed.path)
    count=count+1
    print(url)
```

but this time it does not work. I think because I am considering a list of strings, rather than directly URLs. The array url is a column in a txt file.
Do you know how I could get those results?

Many thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't this `//design.fanpage.com` be `design.fanpage.com`?

Comment: you don't need the count variable in your for loop

Comment: I don't think your code will give you the answer you specified.

Comment: Hi Sharan, I need to check your answer yet. However, it was not my code in the post. I think it was an edit suggested by another user that I approved (accidentally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def url_extract(link): 
    return urlparse(link).netloc

parsed_urls = []

for url in urls:
    parsed_urls.append(url_extract(url))
```

This code would give you what you need and if you want to print it out:

```
print(parsed_urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
>>> map(lambda url: url.netloc, map(urlparse.urlparse, urls))
['www.ilfoglio.it', 'design.fanpage.com', 'www.fondazioneveronesi.it']
>>>
```

Is that what you want?